# Equivalent definition of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My textbook gives two different definitions for the supremum, but I've been unable to prove them.

**Definition 1**
$E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a set of real numbers.
$\alpha$ :=sup $E$ $\overset {\mathrm{def}} {\Leftrightarrow} $
(1)  $\forall x \in E$ , $x \leq \alpha$ 
(2) If $\gamma < \alpha$ , $\exists x \in E$ : $\gamma < x $

**Definition 2**
$E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a set of real numbers. 
$\alpha$ :=sup $E$ $\overset {\mathrm{def}} {\Leftrightarrow} $
(1) $\forall x \in E$ , $x \leq \alpha$ 
(2) $\forall \varepsilon >0 $, $\exists x \in E$ : $\alpha-\varepsilon<x$

Please tell me the proof Definition 1 $\iff$ Definition 2.

Comment: $y<\alpha \iff \exists \varepsilon>0\, s.t.\,  y=\alpha-\varepsilon$.

Comment: The correspondence is $\gamma\leftrightarrow(\alpha-\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that

$\forall\gamma < \alpha$ , $\exists x \in E$ : $\gamma < x $

and

$\forall \varepsilon >0 $, $\exists x \in E$ : $\alpha-\varepsilon<x$

are equivalent.

Note that

$\gamma < \alpha\iff \alpha-\gamma>0$

and

$\gamma < x \iff \alpha-(\alpha-\gamma)< x$

So, the first proposition is equivalent to

$\forall \alpha-\gamma>0$, $\exists x \in E$ : $\alpha-(\alpha-\gamma)< x$

Now, it is enought to use the change of variable property, in this case $\varepsilon=\alpha-\gamma$. Therefore

$\forall \varepsilon >0 $, $\exists x \in E$ : $\alpha-\varepsilon<x$

Comment: I'm not really sure about the last step. Could you give some reference about that "rule" that you use?
Maybe there are some restrictions, such as that the function $\varepsilon=f(\gamma)$ must be bijective or something like that.

Comment: @Anthonny That's subtle, I think. I asked that here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323732/what-is-the-rule-for-changing-variables-in-quantifiers